# Lambda/boto3/python loop

Tags: python-3.x, lambda, aws-lambda, urllib, boto3

This code acts as an early warning system for ADFS failures, which works fine when run locally. Problem is that when I run it in Lambda, it loops non stop.

In short:

1. lambda_handler() runs pagecheck()
2. pagecheck() produces the info needed then passes 2 lists (msgdet_list,  error_list) and an int (error_count) to notification().
3. notification() collates and prints the output. The output is two key variables (notificationheader and notificationbody).

I've #commentedOut the SNS piece which would usually email the info, and am using print() to instead send the info to CloudWatch logs until I can get the loop sorted. Logs:

[CloudWatch logs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jbZ13.jpg)

If I run this locally, it produces a clean single output. In Lambda, the function will loop until it times out. It's almost like every time the lists are updated, they're passed to the notification() module and it's run. I can limit the function time, but would rather fix the code!

Cheers,
tac

```
# This python/boto3/lambda script sends a request to an Office 365 landing page, parses return details to confirm a successful redirect to /
# the organisation ADFS homepage, authenticates homepge is correct, raises any errors, and sends a consolodated report to /
# an AWS SNS topic.
# Run once to produce pageserver and htmlchar values for global variables.

# Import required modules
import boto3
import urllib.request
from urllib.request import Request, urlopen
from datetime import datetime
import time
import re
import sys

# Global variables to be set
url = "https://outlook.com/CONTOSSO.com"
adfslink = "https://sts.CONTOSSO.com/adfs/ls/?client-request-id="

# Input after first run
pageserver = "Microsoft-HTTPAPI/2.0 Microsoft-HTTPAPI/2.0"
htmlchar = 18600

# Input AWS SNS ARN
snsarn = 'arn:aws:sns:ap-southeast-2:XXXXXXXXXXXXX:Daily_Check_Notifications_CONTOSSO'
sns = boto3.client('sns')

def pagecheck():
    # Present the request to the webpage as if coming from a user in a browser
    user_agent = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64)'
    values = {'name' : 'user'}
    headers = { 'User-Agent' : user_agent }    
    data = urllib.parse.urlencode(values)
    data = data.encode('ascii')

    # "Null" the Message Detail and Error lists
    msgdet_list = []
    error_list = []

    request = Request(url)
    req = urllib.request.Request(url, data, headers)
    response = urlopen(request)

    with urllib.request.urlopen(request) as response:

        # Get the URL. This gets the real URL. 
        acturl = response.geturl()
        msgdet_list.append("\nThe Actual URL is:")
        msgdet_list.append(str(acturl))

        if adfslink not in acturl:
            error_list.append(str("Redirect Fail"))

        # Get the HTTP resonse code
        httpcode = response.code
        msgdet_list.append("\nThe HTTP code is: ")
        msgdet_list.append(str(httpcode))

        if httpcode//200 != 1:
            error_list.append(str("No HTTP 2XX Code"))

        # Get the Headers as a dictionary-like object
        headers = response.info()
        msgdet_list.append("\nThe Headers are:")
        msgdet_list.append(str(headers))

        if response.info() == "":
            error_list.append(str("Header Error"))

        # Get the date of request and compare to UTC (DD MMM YYYY HH MM)
        date = response.info()['date']
        msgdet_list.append("The Date is: ")
        msgdet_list.append(str(date))
        returndate = str(date.split( )[1:5])
        returndate = re.sub(r'[^\w\s]','',returndate)
        returndate = returndate[:-2]
        currentdate = datetime.utcnow()
        currentdate = currentdate.strftime("%d %b %Y %H%M")

        if returndate != currentdate:
            date_error = ("Date Error. Returned Date: ", returndate, "Expected Date: ", currentdate, "Times in UTC (DD MMM YYYY HH MM)")
            date_error = str(date_error)
            date_error = re.sub(r'[^\w\s]','',date_error)
            error_list.append(str(date_error))

        # Get the server
        headerserver = response.info()['server']
        msgdet_list.append("\nThe Server is: ")
        msgdet_list.append(str(headerserver))

        if pageserver not in headerserver:
            error_list.append(str("Server Error"))

        # Get all HTML data and confirm no major change to content size by character lenth (global var: htmlchar).
        html = response.read()
        htmllength = len(html)
        msgdet_list.append("\nHTML Length is: ")
        msgdet_list.append(str(htmllength))
        msgdet_list.append("\nThe Full HTML is: ")
        msgdet_list.append(str(html))
        msgdet_list.append("\n")

        if htmllength // htmlchar != 1:
            error_list.append(str("Page HTML Error - incorrect # of characters"))

        if adfslink not in str(acturl):
            error_list.append(str("ADFS Link Error"))

        error_list.append("\n")
        error_count = len(error_list)

        if error_count == 1:
            error_list.insert(0, 'No Errors Found.')
        elif error_count == 2:
            error_list.insert(0, 'Error Found:')
        else:
            error_list.insert(0, 'Multiple Errors Found:')

        # Pass completed results and data to the notification() module
        notification(msgdet_list, error_list, error_count)

# Use AWS SNS to create a notification email with the additional data generated
def notification(msgdet_list, error_list, errors):
    datacheck = str("\n".join(msgdet_list))
    errorcheck = str("\n".join(error_list))
    notificationbody = str(errorcheck + datacheck)

    if errors >1:
        result = 'FAILED!'
    else:
        result = 'passed.'
    notificationheader = ('The daily ADFS check has been marked as ' + result + ' ' + str(errors) + ' ' + str(error_list))

    if result != 'passed.':

        # message = sns.publish(
        #     TopicArn = snsarn,
        #     Subject = notificationheader,
        #     Message = notificationbody
        # )

        # Output result to CloudWatch logstream
        print('Response: ' + notificationheader)

    else:
        print('passed')

    sys.exit()

# Trigger the Lambda handler
def lambda_handler(event, context):
    aws_account_ids = [context.invoked_function_arn.split(":")[4]]
    pagecheck()
    return "Successful"
    sys.exit()
```

Comment: Your code does not have a section that loops. What error are you getting and what are the Lambda settings?

Comment: That's what's getting me, there are no loops yet Lambda is running this over and over. Settings are 128mb + whatever seconds, it still goes until timeout. The log link above shows the errors, I've tried removing all sys.exit() calls and tried adding them in everywhere to break it, no change. Like I said works perfectly if run locally, it's only Lambda that's looping it.

Comment: Time timeout is set independently from memory.

Comment: Another idea is that AWS Lambda is automatically retrying your function since it failed. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/retries-on-errors.html. Set the Lambda timeout to be the max for testing (300 seconds).

Comment: Thanks John, my gut feeling was that Lambda was picking up the sys.exits as unsuccessful completions and running the function again. For testing I have timeout set to 15 secs which is enough for it to loop 3 times and triggered every minute.

Comment: OK - I think sys.exit() is the problem. I don't use sys.exit() in my lambda code, but I do when testing on my desktop so I overlooked that. You should do a normal return and only log errors if the happen. Note: You do not need to set your timeouts so tight. I always set the max timeout in development. Since you are making request() calls, you cannot control network response time that closely. Just use the timeouts to stop a while loop that would run forever type of bugs.

Comment: John you should put ^ as an answer :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your CloudWatch logs contain the following error message:

> Process exited before completing request

This is caused by invoking `sys.exit()` in your code. Locally your Python interpreter will just terminate when encountering such a `sys.exit()`.

AWS Lambda on the other hand expects a Python function to just `return` and handles `sys.exit()` as an error. As your function probably got [invoked asynchronously AWS Lambda retries to execute it twice](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/retries-on-errors.html).

To solve your problem, you can replace the occurences of `sys.exit()` with `return` or even better, just remove the `sys.exit()` calls, as there would be already implicit returns in the places where you use `sys.exit()`.

Comment: This issue is part-way solved: as per my suspicions + John’s comments above, using sys.exit() was causing Lambda to see the function as erroring out and therefore it was retrying. Removing sys.exits reduces the CloudWatch output to 1 log set per invocation, however when introducing messaging it still double taps SNS (2 emails per function if SNS is called). Re: the function time, it averages at about 6-8 seconds so a 15 second function time isn’t too tightly controlled, it’s enough to see the logs produced 3+ times which proves the error.

Comment: Given the handler was triggered by a CloudWatch cron expression my thoughts are that the retry was as a result of non-stream/synchronous invocations though? To be fair and given I #commentedout  the SNS piece, I raised this as a second question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51705061/lambda-boto3-python-issue